# How do I remove @ symbol from first of the word using regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have 
word sequences like

```
@ ABC
@ ABCCD
@CDSFSF
@SDDSD
@SFSFS
```

100000 words in number
I need code to remove @ symbol from all word sequence.

Comment: Use `String.replace()`.

Comment: I think you also need something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/string-split-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way to implement it, is of course, [replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String exampleValue = "@ CDSFSF";

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++) {
    exampleValue.replaceFirst("^@\\s+", "");
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end - start);
```

It takes about 350 milliseconds on my computer.

But [replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method creates [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) instance for each invoke.

```
String exampleValue = "@ CDSFSF";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^@\\s+");
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++) {
    pattern.matcher(exampleValue).replaceFirst("");
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end - start);
```

It takes about 150 milliseconds on my computer. More than two times faster.

But if all your cases look like "@  XXXXX" you can write a code which find first letter in the word and get [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) after that:

```
String exampleValue = "@ CDSFSF";

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000 ; i++) {
    char[] array = exampleValue.toCharArray();
    int c = 0;
    for (; c < array.length;c++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(array[c])) {
            break;
        }
    }
    exampleValue.substring(c);
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end - start);
```

It takes about 30 milliseconds on my computer. The fastest one.

If I were you I would use second solution with [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, because it simple and fast.

Comment: @mykhalo, For me your third method suites very well as it my words contains Unicode characters..

Comment: Great. Feel free to use it ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^@", "");
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/JbPQz8)

Comment: @karu 1000000 is not that large a number, I doubt that you would see issues running this in a loop. [ideone ran 1000000 replacements in 1.38s](http://ideone.com/ueeeIU).

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Then he needs to do this in a loop, one line at a time (it looks like he's got one word per line).

Comment: @karu start position can be start of the line **or** first character in a word...what do you want?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks, Got it! the  time is taken for accessing corpora. Code works fine...

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ @ ആവാം 
@ കൊല്ലം 
@ ഹൈവേ  These are my words I need ആവാം Instead of  @ ആവാം Words are aligned line by line

Answer (score 0):

to remove @ from all words

```
(?<=\s|^)@
```

So it would be

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=\\s|^)@", "");
```